# NSDate to NSString issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have a small issue with NSDate.
I need an NSDate object with the "today date" of other places (for example Australia/Brisbane, while I'm in Italy).

What I'm doing now is to define timeZone as:

```
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Australia/Brisbane"];
```

create an NSDateFormatter:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
```

obtain an NSString:

```
NSString *todayNSString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

The problem is when I try to re-convert the NSString to NSDate.

Let's say my local (Italy) date/time is 2015-03-25 13:52:00 CET.

In this case todayNSString = "Mar 25, 2015, 10:52 PM" (in Australia/Brisbane)

If I convert todayNSString back to an NSDate object with:

```
todayNSDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:todayNSString];
```

I obtain:
todayNSDate = 2015-03-25 13:52:00 CET (that is Italy time)

while I would expect:

```
todayNSDate = 2015-03-25 22:52:00
```

Is there anything wrong in the last line of code or my expectation is not correct ?

Thanks,
Corrado

Comment: You should be use the [`locale`](NSDateFormatter) not the `timeZone` no the `NSDateFormatter `. The `locale` is used localize the date, the `timeZone` is only used to calculate to time zone offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao Corrado,
no, there's nothing wrong, just your idea of NSDate.

Consider that a NSDate is **always** the Date (day+hour) of London.

It's just when you try to print it out in a string that it's "translated/converted" in a different time/hour.

So, when you convert back your string (in Australian format) to a NSDate you get the right London time (because dateFormatter knows the string you are passing is in australian format).

Then when you make a NSLog of it you get the London time,

```
NSLog(@"todayNSDate: %@", todayNSDate);
```

meaning you get the time of London when in Australia it is "Mar 25, 2015, 10:52 PM"

It's up to you to print it in a different way, again with a different NSDateFormatter...

if you try this code:

```
NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
LOG(@"1:::NOW::: %@", now); // input date: 1:::NOW::: 2015-03-25 13:51:36 +0000 (LONDON TIME

NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Australia/Brisbane"];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
NSString *todayNSString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
LOG(@"2:::todayNSString::: %@", todayNSString); // output STRING: 2:::todayNSString::: 25/mar/2015 23:58 (Australian NSSTring)

NSDate* todayNSDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:todayNSString];
LOG(@"3:::NOW::: %@", todayNSDate); // output date: 3:::NOW::: 2015-03-25 13:51:00 +0000 (LONDON TIME)
```

you can see that the first date printed is equal to the reconverted one (but the seconds, cut out because you used dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle)

Comment: Grazie ! Now it's more clear: it was my interpretation of NSDate that was not correct !